# accessing frames in WPF video player

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

What is the easiest way to get a video's individual frame rate, step through a video's frames, and set up some sort of frame buffer to pre-load subsequent frames with a video player made in WPF? I know about DirectShow, but it seems to be more useful for people who want to modify the frames of the video. I just want to be able to step through a video frame by frame, navigate to a specific frame, and normalize the frame rates of multiple videos playing at once (for example, three videos with 10 fps, 20 fps, and 30 fps respectively would play simultaneously at 10 fps).

Answer (score 2):

Over at MSDN, the info on **frame stepping** is hidden at the bottom of the page that is concerned with the scrubbing<sup>1</sup> operation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee892370(v=vs.85).aspx

> The application can perform frame stepping by setting the playback
>   rate to zero and then passing a PROPVARIANT that is set to VT_EMPTY in
>   the call to IMFMediaSession::Start.

Of course these are `COM interfaces` and the link is talking about the `Enhanced Video Renderer` (EVR) and `Windows Media Foundation` which are hardly ready to just drop into your WPF app. I do realize that that's what the questioner was looking for.

So I guess the answer is that, while it's quite a gigantic challenge, it is possible to frame step a video in WPF by p/Invoking to `DirectShowLib.dll` to access the Media Foundataion and EVR. See the `WpfMediaKit`, mentioned elsewhere on this page.

---

[edit:] more information on frame stepping here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530107(v=vs.85).aspx#implementingframestepping

1: jog control browsing of the video file

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid the mediaplayer for wpf doesnt do what you are after.  The closest it does is allow you to seek to a particular time, not a frame.

It may be worth taking a look at [wpfmediakit](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=wpfmediakit&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/&ei=o_0cT634E8qiiAexupH6Cw&usg=AFQjCNHGJcEbJ2QnQ3GoI5kbxC0DKXJnZA&sig2=dMq1mHeN-Ejd5BoUoWvpUw) as a basis to create a custom player to seek frame by frame but it is a longshot.

To get frame by frame control over a variety of codecs, then you will have to use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) which is not setup for wpf